# Binding keys to start and stop with tkinter

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter, bind

If I wanted to use keys instead of buttons how and where should i bind them?
Tim helped me on a resizing issue but my simple code has turned quite complex. I was playing about and have come along way with python. my aim is to scrap using button and bind some keys to start/stop and flash
should i create a new class for these functions or are they okay in the main?
also if i wanted it to go fullscreen on start is it best to pop overideredirect into my redraw class?

```
import tkinter
import time

class ReDraw():
    def __init__(self):
        self._tk = tkinter.Tk()

        self._myframe = tkinter.Frame(master = self._tk)
        self._myframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.NSEW)

        self._mycanvas = tkinter.Canvas(master = self._tk, width = 850, height = 400, bg = 'grey', highlightthickness = 0)
        self._mycanvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.NSEW) 

        self._mycanvas.bind("<Configure>", self._on_resize)

        self._tk.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self._tk.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.fracX = 1
        self.fracY = 1

        self._oval1 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

    def _on_resize(self, event):
        self._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        self.fracX = event.width/850
        self.fracY = event.height/400
        self._oval1 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._mycanvas.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

def main():
    canvas = ReDraw()
    # Some widgets to the canvas
    def red0(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)            
    def red1(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                
    def red2(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval3')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                 
    def red3(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval1')
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval2')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval3')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval4')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval4') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                
    def red4(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete('oval5')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval5') 
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)     
    def green(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval1')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval2')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval3')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval4')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval5')
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    def lights():
        canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
        canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')
        canvas._tk.update()
    def lights1(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    def amber(a):
        for i in range(a):
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            canvas._oval1 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(50*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,160*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval1')
            canvas._oval2 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(210*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,320*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval2')
            canvas._oval3 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(370*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,480*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval3')
            canvas._oval4 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(530*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,640*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval4')
            canvas._oval5 = canvas._mycanvas.create_oval(690*canvas.fracX,50*canvas.fracY,800*canvas.fracX,160*canvas.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval5')
            canvas._tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)
    # tag all of the drawn widgets
    def flashing():
        while True:
            amber(12)
            lights1(10)

    def stop():
        while True:
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            lights()
            canvas._tk.update()            

    def start():
        while True:
            canvas._mycanvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)
            lights()
            canvas._tk.update()
            lights1(20)
            red0(35)
            red1(35)
            red2(35)
            red3(35)
            red4(35)
            green(90)
            lights()
            break



    canvas._but1 = tkinter.Button(text="start", command=start)
    canvas._but1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="w")
    canvas._but2 = tkinter.Button(text="amber", command=flashing)
    canvas._but2.grid(row = 2, sticky="w", padx=(80))
    canvas._but1 = tkinter.Button(text="stop", command=stop)
    canvas._but1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="w", padx=(40))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

as a quick example to understand something like this...

```
import tkinter

class ReDraw():
        def __init__(self):
            self._tk = tkinter.Tk()

            self._myframe = tkinter.Frame(master = self._tk)
            self._myframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tkinter.NSEW)

class main(tk.Frame):
    def main(tk.Frame):
         canvas._but1 = tkinter.Button(text="start", command=start)
         canvas._but1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="w")

class MyCanvas(tkinter.Canvas):
    def MyCanvas(tkinter.Canvas)
        canvas = ReDraw()
        # Some widgets to the canvas
        def red0(a):
```

Comment: unrelated to your question, as a general rule of thumb  you should never call `sleep` in a GUI since it causes your GUI to do exactly that -- sleep. It will make the UI less responsive, because it can't react to events while it is sleeping.

Comment: I thought sleep() was if you update. what would you recommend? tkinter.after()? i'm not familiar with using after() can i just replace sleep() with it?

Answer (score 0):

You would create class `Main(tk.Frame)` with `tkinter.Tk` and `Frame` and second class `MyCanvas(tkinter.Canvas)` with all functions which are doing something with canvas.

---

**EDIT:**

It still isn't what I was thinking about but at least it works.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

class App():

    def __init__(self):

        self._tk = tk.Tk()

        self._tk.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self._tk.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self._myframe = tk.Frame(master = self._tk)
        self._myframe.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

        self._mycanvas = MyCanvas(self._tk)

        self._tk._but1 = tk.Button(self._tk, text="start", command=self._mycanvas.start)
        self._tk._but1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="w")
        self._tk._but2 = tk.Button(self._tk, text="amber", command=self._mycanvas.flashing)
        self._tk._but2.grid(row = 2, sticky="w", padx=(80))
        self._tk._but1 = tk.Button(self._tk, text="stop", command=self._mycanvas.stop)
        self._tk._but1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky="w", padx=(40))

        self._tk.bind("s", self._mycanvas.start)
        self._tk.bind("w", self._mycanvas.stop)

        self._tk.mainloop()


class MyCanvas():

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent = parent

        self._myself = tk.Canvas(master = parent, width = 850, height = 400, bg = 'grey', highlightthickness = 0)
        self._myself.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW) 

        self.fracX = 1
        self.fracY = 1

        self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._myself.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._myself.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

        self._started = False

        self._myself.bind("<Configure>", self._on_resize)

    def _on_resize(self, event):

        self._myself.delete(tk.ALL)

        self.fracX = event.width/850
        self.fracY = event.height/400

        self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._myself.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._myself.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')

    # Some widgets to the canvas
    def red0(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete('oval1')
            self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)           

    def red1(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete('oval1')
            self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            self._myself.delete('oval2')
            self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)

    def red2(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete('oval1')
            self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            self._myself.delete('oval2')
            self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            self._myself.delete('oval3')
            self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                 

    def red3(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete('oval1')
            self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval1') 
            self._myself.delete('oval2')
            self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval2') 
            self._myself.delete('oval3')
            self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval3') 
            self._myself.delete('oval4')
            self._oval4 = self._myself.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval4') 
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)                

    def red4(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete('oval5')
            self._oval5 = self._myself.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="red", tags = 'oval5') 
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)     

    def green(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete(tk.ALL)
            self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval1')
            self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval2')
            self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval3')
            self._oval4 = self._myself.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval4')
            self._oval5 = self._myself.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="green", tags = 'oval5')
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)

    def lights(self):
        self._myself.delete(tk.ALL)
        self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
        self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
        self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
        self._oval4 = self._myself.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
        self._oval5 = self._myself.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')
        self.parent.update()

    def lights1(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete(tk.ALL)
            self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval1')
            self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval2')
            self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval3')
            self._oval4 = self._myself.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval4')
            self._oval5 = self._myself.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="black", tags = 'oval5')
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)

    def amber(self, a):
        for i in range(a):
            self._myself.delete(tk.ALL)
            self._oval1 = self._myself.create_oval(50*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,160*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval1')
            self._oval2 = self._myself.create_oval(210*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,320*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval2')
            self._oval3 = self._myself.create_oval(370*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,480*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval3')
            self._oval4 = self._myself.create_oval(530*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,640*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval4')
            self._oval5 = self._myself.create_oval(690*self.fracX,50*self.fracY,800*self.fracX,160*self.fracY, fill="yellow", tags = 'oval5')
            self.parent.update()
            time.sleep(0.05)

    # tag all of the drawn widgets
    def flashing(self):
        if not self._started:
            self.amber(12)
            self.lights1(10)
        self._myself.after(100, self.flashing)

    def stop(self, extra=None):
        if self._started:
            self._started = False
            self._myself.delete(tk.ALL)
            self.parent.update()            

    def start(self, extra=None):
        if not self._started:
            self._started = True
            self._myself.delete(tk.ALL)
            self.lights()
            self.lights1(20)
            self.red0(35)
            self.red1(35)
            self.red2(35)
            self.red3(35)
            self.red4(35)
            self.green(90)
            self.lights()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App()
```

---

`class MyCanvas():` should be `class MyCanvas(tk>Canvas):` and then you need `tk.Canvas.__init__(...)` in `MyCanvas.__init__(...)` and you don't need `self._myself = tk.Canvas(...)` and `self` will be already the canvas (in place of `self._myself`).

Comment: see my example in answer.

Comment: Thanks that's fixed the issue with launching. so just to clarify basically the program wasn't starting outside of idle because it didn't have a mainloop. so now if we wanted to bind keys to start and stop it instead of buttons is it possible ( i'm guessing not lol) to  change    self._tk._but1 = tk.bind(self._tk, "<w>", self._mycanvas.stop) i'm not at home to check, thanks again furas for helping

Comment: Yes. Script need `mainloop()` to work (all GUI has some kind of `mainloop`). IDLE use `Tkinter` run `mainloop()` so script worked without `mainloop()` but I use it always.

Comment: You can still bind `keys`, `mouse` and other events. You can bind to any widget - probably if you bind to main windget (root) then it will be available in all script - global binding - `self._tk.bind("w", self._mycanvas.stop)`

Comment: Well Thanks again. just out of interest why is my qustion been downvoted,I know i'm not the best at explaining myself, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I think we posted at the same time. by Root you mean in App class?

Comment: I add bindings in answer. See also `after()` in `flashing()` - it flash yellow lights every 100ms and doesn't stop Tkinter - Tkinter can run its own functions (in `mainloop`). I add `self._started` to somehow control ligths.

Comment: SO is rather for questions about errors in code then about opinion `Is this the correct` - so people downvote.

Comment: ah I was looking into "after()" after byran said not to use time.sleep in GUI apps

Comment: seems to have trouble stopping and starting it, if i added self.light() between delete and update is the loop going to conintue under the black circles?

Comment: I didn't test everything. I add only `after()` to show how it works. Make own tests using `print` - to see which functions are executed.

Comment: Im on it thank you I'll post back with what i come up with :)